# How to suppress output of link with elisp function in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-link

When using elisp function in the link in org-mode, like

```
[[elisp:(func)][text]]
```

after clicking the link, the function itself will be printed in *Message* buffer. How should I prevent it from being printed? I've tried

```
(let ((inhibit-output t))
  (...))
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

[Editorial comment: I'm not convinced this is a good idea - what difference does it make if the `*Messages*` buffer has an extra line in it? Despite my misgivings, I provide an answer below.]

The relevant function is `org-link--open-elisp`. If you check its implementation, you will see that it uses `message` to print the result of the evaluation to the echo area. But `message` also copies whatever it prints to the echo area, to the `*Messages*` buffer. A quick perusal of the doc string for `message` shows that you can avoid copying to the `*Messages*` buffer if you set `message-log-max` to `nil`. Unfortunately, that is going to turn off *all* output to the *Messages* buffer which is a bad thing.

One way to accomplish what you want is to patch the `org-link--open-elisp` function to bind `message-log-max` to nil temporarily (as Marco Wahl suggests in his answer), but my suggestion would be to write a new function for this, which is an exact copy of `org-link--open-elisp` except that it binds `message-log-max` to `nil` before calling `message`:

```
(defun org-link--open-elisp-silent (path)
  "Open a \"elisp-silent\" type link.
PATH is the sexp to evaluate, as a string."
  (if (or (and (org-string-nw-p org-link-elisp-skip-confirm-regexp)
           (string-match-p org-link-elisp-skip-confirm-regexp path))
      (not org-link-elisp-confirm-function)
      (funcall org-link-elisp-confirm-function
           (format "Execute %S as Elisp? "
               (org-add-props path nil 'face 'org-warning))))
      (let ((message-log-max nil))
         (message "%s => %s" path
           (if (eq ?\( (string-to-char path))
           (eval (read path))
         (call-interactively (read path)))))
    (user-error "Abort")))
```

You can then add a new link type "elisp-silent"  that is handled by this function:

```
(org-link-set-parameters "elisp-silent" :follow #'org-link--open-elisp-silent)
```

Now `[[elisp:(func)][verbose]]` works as before and `[[elisp-silent:(func)][silent]]` works the same way but avoids writing to the `*Messages*` buffer.

This technique of binding a variable around a function call is general and well-worth understanding if you are going to be doing elisp programming.

Comment: I like the idea of introducing a new protocol for that purpose.

Comment: What is wrong on `(defun org-link--open-elisp-silent (path) (let (message-log-max) (org-link--open-elisp path)))`?

Comment: Nothing (as I know you know :-)): I was just being stupid.

Answer (score 1):

A shorter way to accomplish this is by [Advising Emacs Lisp Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html). You can use `:around` advice to let-bind the variable and then call the original function with its arguments like this:

```
(defun silence (orig-func &rest args)
  (let ((message-log-max nil))
    (apply orig-func args)))

(advice-add 'org-link--open-elisp :around 'silence)
```

Later you can remove the advice like this:

```
(advice-remove 'org-link--open-elisp 'silence)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the message comes from the respective org mode function you need to somehow circumvent that function.  You could patch that function.

Actually I think it's a good idea to see the message since this gives transparency to the evaluation.  Note that the code evaluation could bring irritation and even harm.